# Calling abstract method in livedata callback

Tags: java, android

I have an abstract parent class, with some abstract methods. Now I have 4 children of this super class. I am observing a livedata in the super class, like below :

```
 viewModel.getSignedS3LiveData().observe(this, commonResponse -> {
        if(commonResponse != null)
        {
            handleSignedS3Response(commonResponse);     //abstract method
        }
    });
```

Where handleSignedS3Response is an abstract method.

The scenario is that I have 4 fragments that extend this super class and are added to the backstack one after the other(so 4 steps).

When step 1 is added the correct implementation method for handleSignedS3Response is called, which is in fragment 1.

When I move from fragment1 to fragment2 handleSignedS3Response is called in fragment 1 and not in fragment2.

Also this is only happening for methods that I call inside the livedata callback. There are other abstract that are called correctly even for the fragment2 that are not in the livedata callback.

Please help me out with this. If there is anything that i am not able to explaing clearly please ask.

Comment: All the `registered observers of the livedata will be called` , in your case the method will be called **twice** both from fragment 1 and 2. You should kill fragment1 or remove the observer from fragment 1 while fragment transaction to avoid the method to get called twice !

Comment: if that was the case I would get calls in both the implementation methods. Even if that was happening i would have handled this.

Comment: One cannot call `abstract` methods, but only their implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this:

```
abstract class SuperClass(private val factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory) : Fragment() {
    abstract fun imaginaryMethod()

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        activity?.let {
            val vm = ViewModelProvider(it::getViewModelStore, factory).get(TheViewModel::class.java)
            vm.aliveData.observe(it, Observer {
                imaginaryMethod()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Fragment1(private val factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory) : SuperClass() {
    override fun imaginaryMethod() {
        println("FRAGMENT1 IMAGINED")
    }
}
```

```
class Fragment2(private val factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory) : SuperClass() {
    override fun imaginaryMethod() {
        println("FRAGMENT2 IMAGINED")
    }
}
```

This is how I usually do it and it works for me. I also normally use dagger to provide the factory. But this also works too.

Factory from Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val factory = ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(Fragment1(factory), null).addToBackStack("hello").commit()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(Fragment2(factory), null).addToBackStack("hello").commit()
    }
```

Results from console:

```
I/System.out: FRAGMENT1 IMAGINED
    FRAGMENT2 IMAGINED
```